# The best way to parse HTML tags in java-script

Tags: php, javascript, html, html-parsing

can anybody help/advice that is there any way to parse HTML tags appear in side the `<body>...</body>` tags

Comment: I think we'll need some more detail as to what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you want to parse a HTML document using PHP. I suggest you read about the http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Here is an example provided by [PHP Pro](http://www.phpro.org/examples/Parse-HTML-With-PHP-And-DOM.html)

```
<?php

$html = '
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
<head>
<title>PHPRO.ORG</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Forecast for Saturday</h2>
<!-- Issued at 0828 UTC Friday 23 May 2008 -->
<table border="0" summary="Capital Cities Precis Forecast">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><a href="/products/IDN10064.shtml" title="Link to Sydney forecast">Sydney</a></td>
         <td title="Maximum temperature in degrees Celsius" class="max alignright">19&deg;</td>
         <td>Fine. Mostly sunny.</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
         <td><a href="/products/IDV10450.shtml" title="Link to Melbourne forecast">Melbourne</a></td>
         <td title="Maximum temperature in degrees Celsius" class="max alignright">16&deg;</td>
         <td>Fog then fine.</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
         <td><a href="/products/IDQ10095.shtml" title="Link to Brisbane forecast">Brisbane</a></td>
         <td title="Maximum temperature in degrees Celsius" class="max alignright">24&deg;</td>
         <td>Mostly fine</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
         <td><a href="/products/IDW12300.shtml" title="Link to Perth forecast">Perth</a></td>
         <td title="Maximum temperature in degrees Celsius" class="max alignright">21&deg;</td>
         <td>Few showers, increasing later.</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
         <td><a href="/products/IDS10034.shtml" title="Link to Adelaide forecast">Adelaide</a></td>
         <td title="Maximum temperature in degrees Celsius" class="max alignright">20&deg;</td>
         <td>Fine. Mostly sunny.</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
         <td><a href="/products/IDT65061.shtml" title="Link to Hobart forecast">Hobart</a></td>
         <td title="Maximum temperature in degrees Celsius" class="max alignright">13&deg;</td>
         <td>Mainly fine.</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
         <td><a href="/products/IDN10035.shtml" title="Link to Canberra forecast">Canberra</a></td>
         <td title="Maximum temperature in degrees Celsius" class="max alignright">15&deg;</td>
         <td>Fine, mostly sunny.</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
         <td><a href="/products/IDD10150.shtml" title="Link to Darwin forecast">Darwin</a></td>
         <td title="Maximum temperature in degrees Celsius" class="max alignright">32&deg;</td>
         <td>Fine and sunny.</td>
      </tr>

   </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
';

    /*** a new dom object ***/
    $dom = new domDocument;

    /*** load the html into the object ***/
    $dom->loadHTML($html);

    /*** discard white space ***/
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

    /*** the table by its tag name ***/
    $tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');

    /*** get all rows from the table ***/
    $rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');

    /*** loop over the table rows ***/
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        /*** get each column by tag name ***/
        $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
        /*** echo the values ***/
        echo $cols->item(0)->nodeValue.'<br />';
        echo $cols->item(1)->nodeValue.'<br />';
        echo $cols->item(2)->nodeValue;
        echo '<hr />';
    }
?>
```

Comment: I thought he was looking for a JavaScript solution, not PHP.

Comment: Me too at first, but noticed the tag

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like [John Resig's html parser](http://ejohn.org/blog/pure-javascript-html-parser/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can load the entire html document via ajax from another page and parse it using jQuery selectors - if it is xhtml. Not sure if it is not well formed whether this will work.